# Can Class.getmethod find the method include type of Class< ? > paramter?

Tags: java

My English is not good,so I just can give you the code and the error message
Codes:

```
  public class ReflectDemo {
  private   void t00(Class<?> unknown,String str)
   {
       System.out.println("t0");
   }
}
   @Test
    public void test01()
    {
        Class<?> unknown= null;
        try {
            Method method= ReflectDemo.class.getDeclaredMethod("t00",unknown,String.class);
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(new ReflectDemo(),"a","b");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error message:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Demo.ReflectDemo.t00(null, java.lang.String)
How can I get the method of t00?

Comment: Can you add the full StackTrace

Comment: If for `String`, you do `String.class`, then what should you do for `Class`?

Comment: `getDeclaredMethod("t00",Class.class,String.class)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass `null` as the value of a parameter to `getDeclaredMethod`.

Pass the class literal instead:

```
ReflectDemo.class.getDeclaredMethod("t00", Class.class,String.class)
```

Note that your `invoke` will then fail, because `"a"` is not an instance of `Class<?>`.

Comment: `invoke` will succeed if you change it to  `method.invoke(new ReflectDemo(), String.class, "b");`